# Alert box doesn't display anything

Tags: java, jsp, web

The JSP is:

```
<input type="submit" value="GENERATE TICKET" class="button" name="generate" onclick="myFunction()">
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert(
    <%SelectCustomer sc = new SelectCustomer();
    System.out.println(sc.getCash());%>
    );
}
</script>
```

The java class is:

```
public class SelectCustomer
{
    public int getCash() throws SQlException
    {
        return 12;
    }
}
```

The alert box pops but is blank.
What is the reason?
How to print 12 in the alert box?

Comment: What does the resulting javascript look like once the page is rendered? Can you open the browser dev console and inspect the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>`.

Also make sure you are using quotes inside of your alert function call.

Comment: still gives an error: **illegal start of expression**

Comment: What about wrapping the output in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

try this code 
add an input hidden were you put the wanted value

```
<input type='hidden' name='' id='data' value=' <%= VALUE-HERE  %>' />
```

Then JS :

```
var content =document.getElementById('data').getAttribute('value');
alert(content);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try with this script:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    <%  Windowlogin sc = new Windowlogin();%>   
        alert(<%=sc.getCash()%>);   
}
</script>
```

Comment: Kindly change the class name from Windowlogin to SelectCustomer as I was using test class with name Windowlogin. And let me know if it is not working.